# Remove second level category from product url

Tags: product, category, product-urls

I need to display only first level category inside product url. If visitors browse and click product inside categorylevel1/categorylevel2.html, I need to show domain.com/categorylevel1/product.html and NOT domain.com/categorylevel1/categorylevel2/product.html

Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Does the answer provided work? I'm looking for the same funcionality.

Comment: I didn't find any solution, but I didn't made any further research, I just simple didn't use second level categories but I went with only one level structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can get product url path form `Url Rewrite collection`

```
$path = Mage::getResourceModel('core/url_rewrite')->getRequestPathByIdPath('product/{product_id}/{category_id}', Mage::app()->getStore());
```

Parameter

```
{product_id} => your product Id 
{category_id} => your first level category id.
```

Now you can get the product Url like

```
Mage::getBaseUrl().$path
```

or

```
$this->getUrl('', array('_direct' => $path));
```

**Note**: product must be assign with both category (i.e., first level and second level category)

I have refer this [**link**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52969/get-product-path-from-id-with-category-path-in-url)